# compute precision, recall, F1 values for rpart package result

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, rpart, precision-recall

The below data frame is a sample of my total data set:

```
A    B   C    D    E    target
0.2 0.5 0.6 -0.5   -0.7   1
0.9 0.7 0.4 -0.3   -0.8   0  
0.1 0.3 0.5 -0.9   -0.2   0
0.2 0.5 0.6 -0.5   -0.6   1
```

I want to apply classification tree on that so I used the below code:

```
data$target<-factor(data$target)

# Create Training Data
train.ind <- sample(nrow(data), 0.7*nrow(data))
trainData<-data[train.ind,]
testData<-data[-train.ind,]    

library("rpart")
tree <- rpart(target ~.,data=trainData)

ypred=predict(tree,testData)

    library(caret)
    #Print a confusion matrix
    result <- confusionMatrix(ypred,testData$target)
```

> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

```
   precision <- result$byClass['Pos Pred Value']    
    recall <- result$byClass['Sensitivity']
    f_measure <- 2 * ((precision * recall) / (precision + recall))
    #OR
    f_measure <-result$byClass['F1']
```

But it did not work. I need to the precision, recall and F1 values but I don't know how to compute using "rpart" package result.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Are you getting an error (if yes, where?) or an unexpected result (if yes, why did you expect something else?)?

Comment: @jkd I can't compute the confusion matrix. I added the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `confusionMatrix` takes two arguments (`data` and `reference`) which have to be factors with the same levels. This is not the case with your code because the `predict` function, when given an `rpart`-object, returns a matrix with probabilities of  class memberships for each sample by default. You need to specify to this function that you want a vector of predicted classes and convert this vector to a factor with the same levels as `target` (`0` and `1`).

This should do the trick:

```
ypred <- factor(predict(tree, testData[, -6], type="vector"),
                levels = levels(testData$target))
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(ypred, testData$target)
```

Using `factor(..., levels = levels(testData$target))` ensures that the levels are in the same order in both factors to avoid following warning:

> Warning message: In confusionMatrix.default(ypred, testData$target) : 
>   Levels are not in the same order for reference and data. Refactoring
>   data to match.

Comment: @minoo I re-edited your edit to my answer to avoid hard-coding the order of the factors. This should always work ;)